# Breakpoints is not hitting during Debug in visual studio

Tags: c#

when debugging, in symbol status under Modules it is displaying "binary is not built with debug information" for few dll's related to Nunit, when i debug by attaching the Nunit Process.
Is due to this "binary is not built with debug information" breakpoints is not hitting?
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Are you on debug mode?

Comment: ya my solution  is in debugging mode

Answer (score 0):

Most release binaries are built without debug information not only for performance reasons. If you want to take a look at the nunit code, you might find tools like ILSpy useful.

Comment: so are you telling the "binary is not built with debug information" is not related with the issue "breakpoints is not hitting during the debug of the code".

Comment: No, I wanted to show that it is pretty normal that you cannot debug 3rd party binaries because it is normal that they do not come with debug information. Do you have source code of nunit to set your breakpoint in?
Anyway I wonder why you would debug nunit binaries?

Comment: Ok,actually i new to VS IDE i am not sure about why the breakpoints are not hitting,under modules for my colleagues they are getting "symbols skipped" ,for main dll for which i will opening in Nunit the symbols are loading.

Comment: But for me under symbol status for few dll's related to Nunit it was showing "binary is not built with debug information"which was not appearing in my colleagues IDE ,that's why i wanted to make clear is this the reason"binary is not built with debug information" for breakpoints not getting hitted.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the reason why your break points do not get hit.

Comment: ok.can you please tell me what i can i do to get rid of this .

Answer (score -1):

if you are working with window service or Console Application then you have to change the dropdown value to Debug. i am adding the attachment
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYCHE.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).